# Custom Membership, MVC and WCF. Where to implement it?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

I have a complicated question, at least for me :), and it's more architecture than coding, i would say.

Ok, I am creating a MVC website. I have a wcf service and that's my only way of communication with my database, business objects, etc.

- Website (MVC)
- Hosting Layer (WCF)
- Service Layer (interface and impletementation for the WCF - class library)
- Business Layer (class library)
- Data Layer (Plinqo - L2S)
- Framework (class library - here i have my custom membership)

in other words, in my web.config at the mvc layer i don't have any connection string, just the web service mambo jambo. i have the default membership and role provider not implemented.

I implemented a custom Membership and Role Provider. BUT, i use it at the service layer level (i declared it at the WCF's web.config) It means that, from the MVC i call my webservice client's validate method (client.ValidateUser(User)) and it's then when i do my Membership.ValidateUser(username, password).

If you need to know the reasons i did it this way, i will add it. Just ask me.

My question... In my Controllers, when i add the roles attributes to my methods, i know it's going to fail because mvc is going to try to use whatever membership and role provider is in the webconfig... of course, i haven't implemented it at the mvc level, but at the wcf. so it's going to pop a notImplemented error. i haven't tried but is my guts feeling. SHOULD I IMPLEMENT IT in my mvc and then from this custom membership and role provider call my wcf (database call) and remove it my current membership provider and role provider?

i know it's all tricky and confusing. if you have any doubts, let me know.

thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a custom implementation of the `Authorize` filer and override the `OnAuthorization` method where you have to make the WCF call and do all the work.

http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/07/08/implementing-a-custom-asp.net-mvc-authorization-filter.aspx